# How to Bypass Spring boot Security in Spring boot admin client?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

My team is developed an spring boot business app and its now on production server.
Now my manager wants to implement spring boot admin server to monitor this app( that's may be a good idea).

Now, My situation is, I am using spring boot 2.1.3 version and I created sample spring boot admin server and client and that's working fine. but when I made my business application to spring boot admin client that time I am getting an "health **status= down** ",and my business application security showing logs like **no matching filters**.

We have used strong security for business application.
[image]

Now, my question is can I bypass the security for actuator and How? and Is it good idea to use spring boot admin server (separate application) for business application.

Bellow is the log

```
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/api/getClientByName'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/api/getAuthType'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/api/resetPassword'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/api/sendOTP'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/api/fetchQuestionsList'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/externalApi/**'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.480 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed'; against '/api/**'
28-03-2019 13:47:18.481 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy:202 - /actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed?tag=area:heap has no matching filters
```

Comment: 1. the log statements are on DEBUG level. So don't worry and fix your log config.
2. The status down is obviously because the healthcheck for redis fails
3. Yes SBA should be run as a separate application and not included in the business app (see https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#faqs)

Comment: @joshiste You mean just because of redis is down, my application health is down.

Comment: yes. that is how it works by default

Comment: Thanks @joshiste, But Redis is needed in my application and Spring boot admin is saperate application. Is there any option to show health up If Redis is down or without redis up health will not be up?